# Assist me in finding the formula for Excel

Tags: excel

Can someone help me solve this for an Excel formula

```
     4+y
  __________

  (2x+y)^+12
```

I have tried

```
=(4+y)/(2x+y)^+12
```

and

```
(4+y)/(2*(x)+y)^+12
```

but they are not correct. Please I need help

Comment: Place x and y in two cells and refer to them in your formula

Answer (score 1):

Pick a cell and enter:

```
=(4+Y1)/(2*X1+Y1)^12
```

where **X1** will hold your `x` value and **Y1** will hold your `y` value.